# Why doesn't the last command variable "_" appear in dir()?

Tags: python

First line once Python 2.7 interpreter is started on Windows:

```
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__']
```

Having entered the `dir()` command, the special variable `_` should be defined:

```
>>> _
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__']
```

But, even after entering `_`, it does not show up when I attempt to list all names in the interactive namespace using `dir()`:

```
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__']
```

How does the interpreter recognize this variable if it is not in the interpreter's namespace?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`_` goes in the built-in namespace, not the globals.

```
>>> import __builtin__
>>> 3
3
>>> __builtin__._
3
```

[`dir()` doesn't list built-ins:](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir)

> Without arguments, return the list of names in the current local scope.

The built-in scope is a different scope from the one you're running `dir()` in.